# Pygame couldn't read from resource after a time

Tags: python, crash, resources, pygame

I am a making a Pygame game called Ninja Quest. So far, I have only worked on it for a couple of days however, I find that when I launch the game, everything works fine but, after about 30 seconds, the game will crash, saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "NinjaQuest.py", line 151,
>   in    File "NinjaQuest.py", line 146, in main pygame.error:
>   Couldn't read from 'Resources/Menu/Disasterpeace - Home.ogg'

Although I have only done the menu right now, and none of the options work, I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what is wrong with my code, as I have asked some of my piers, but they couldn't figure out the problem. Thanks in advance :).

By the way, here is my 'NinjaQuest.py':

```
#Imports
from pygame.locals import *; import pygame; from Image import *; from Background import *;
import sys, os

#Constants
FPS = 200
WINDOWWIDTH = 900; WINDOWHEIGHT = 506;
GAMETITLE = "Ninja Quest"; VERSION = "0.5 Pre-Dev"
WHITE = [255,255,255]; RED = [255,0,0]; GREEN = [0,255,0]; BLUE = [0,0,255]; BLACK = [0,0,0]

surface = pygame.display.set_mode([WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption(GAMETITLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

slc = 1

openingFinished = True

''' I define stuff here to avoid doing it in a loop to avoid lag '''

#Draw menu
pygame.font.init()

#Define background
background = Background("Resources/Menu/Background.png", 0, (601 - 506) * -1)

#Define text
titleFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 40)
titleText = titleFont.render("Ninja Quest",True,(255,165,0))

titleFont2 = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
titleText2 = titleFont2.render(VERSION,True,(255,165,0))

newFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,(255,165,0))

loadFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
loadText = loadFont.render("Load Game",True,(255,165,0))

creditFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
creditText = creditFont.render("Credits",True,(255,165,0))

def drawMenu():
    global titleText
    global titleText2
    global newText
    global loadText
    global creditText
    global background

    surface.blit(background.image, background.rect)

    if slc == 1:
        newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,BLUE)
        loadText = newFont.render("Load Game",True,(255,165,0))
        creditText = newFont.render("Credits",True,(255,165,0))

    elif slc == 2:
        loadText = newFont.render("Load Game",True,BLUE)
        newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,(255,165,0))
        creditText = newFont.render("Credits",True,(255,165,0))

    elif slc == 3:
        creditText = newFont.render("Credits",True,BLUE)
        loadText = newFont.render("Load Game",True,(255,165,0))
        newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,(255,165,0))

    surface.blit(titleText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - titleText.get_width() / 2, titleText.get_height()))
    surface.blit(titleText2,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - titleText2.get_width() / 2, titleText.get_height() + titleText.get_height()))
    surface.blit(newText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - newText.get_width() / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT * 0.33333))
    surface.blit(loadText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - newText.get_width() / 2, (WINDOWHEIGHT * 0.33333) + loadText.get_height()))
    surface.blit(creditText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - newText.get_width() / 2, (WINDOWHEIGHT * 0.33333) + creditText.get_height() * 2))

    pygame.display.update()

#Draw opening scene
def drawOpening():
    openingFinished = False
    surface.fill((255,255,255))

    #Play theme tune
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Resources/Menu/8-Bit.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(1000)

    #Draw background
    background = Image("Resources/Menu/The 8-Bit Developers.png", 4, 4, 0, 0)
    background = Image("Resources/Menu/The 8-Bit Developers.png", 4, 4, WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - background.image.get_width() / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2 - background.image.get_height() / 2)
    surface.blit(background.image,background.rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(2000)
    openingFinished = True

#Main Loop
def main(newGame):
    running = True
    global slc
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 10)

    #a = pygame.image.load("Resources/Menu/Icon.png")
    #pygame.display.set_icon(a)

    pygame.init()

    if newGame == True:
        #Start game and then music
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) # setup mixer to avoid sound lag
        surface.fill((255,255,255))
        drawOpening()

        #pygame.mixer.music.load("Resources/Menu/Disasterpeace - Home.ogg")
        pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join("Resources","Menu","Disasterpeace - Home.ogg"))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

    while running:
        #Controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and openingFinished == True:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    slc -= 1
                    if slc == 0:
                        slc = 3

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    slc += 1
                    if slc == 4:
                        slc = 1

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if slc == 1:
                        #new game
                        pass

                    if slc == 2:
                        #resume game
                        pass

                    if slc == 3:
                        #credits
                        pass

        drawMenu()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.mixer.music.queue(os.path.join("Resources","Menu","Disasterpeace - Home.ogg"))
        clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(True)
```

Edit: I am on Mac OS X 10.9 'Maverics' if it helps

Comment: You at least need to show your imports and the code around line 151.  I am wondering immediately if you misnamed your path (Disasterpeace should that be Disasterpiece).  Questions on SO should be written and prepared for eternity.  We generally frown on using links from outside because when you delete the file the question is gone.  I would encourage you to look at the help page, particularly the How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for using a link :/, I didn't realise. I will edit my post shortly. BTW, Disasterpeace is the name, I have checked that many times. The thing is, if the location was wrong, I don't get how it would throw an error, but only after an amount of time. I have had this problem on previous projects too, but with png files.

Comment: Does this path exist 'Resources/Menu/"Disasterpeace - Home.ogg"

Comment: Yes, I have checked it thoroughly. Otherwise it would crash straight away, and not after 30 seconds like it does.

Comment: If you are sure about the path then maybe the file format is wrong - I don't know much about pygame but the error seems explicit and so I would suggest trying some other audio file and see what happens

Comment: Hmm :/.... I have just tried using an mp3 file format, but it still crashes after around 30 seconds. I'm absolutely baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have finally solved my problem! It appears that I can avoid the game crashing if, instead of using pygame.mixer.music.queue() every iteration of my main loop, instead, I just use:

```
if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join("Resources","Menu","Disasterpeace - Home.ogg"))
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

This is the final code:

```
#Imports
from pygame.locals import *; import pygame; from Image import *; from Background import *;
import sys, os

#Constants
FPS = 200
WINDOWWIDTH = 900; WINDOWHEIGHT = 506;
GAMETITLE = "Ninja Quest"; VERSION = "0.5 Pre-Dev"
WHITE = [255,255,255]; RED = [255,0,0]; GREEN = [0,255,0]; BLUE = [0,0,255]; BLACK = [0,0,0]

surface = pygame.display.set_mode([WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption(GAMETITLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

slc = 1

openingFinished = True

''' I define stuff here to avoid doing it in a loop to avoid lag '''

#Draw menu
pygame.font.init()

#Define background
background = Background("Resources/Menu/Background.png", 0, (601 - 506) * -1)

#Define text
titleFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 40)
titleText = titleFont.render("Ninja Quest",True,(255,165,0))

titleFont2 = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
titleText2 = titleFont2.render(VERSION,True,(255,165,0))

newFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,(255,165,0))

loadFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
loadText = loadFont.render("Load Game",True,(255,165,0))

creditFont = pygame.font.Font("Resources/ka1.ttf", 30)
creditText = creditFont.render("Credits",True,(255,165,0))

def drawMenu():
    global titleText
    global titleText2
    global newText
    global loadText
    global creditText
    global background

    surface.blit(background.image, background.rect)

    if slc == 1:
        newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,BLUE)
        loadText = newFont.render("Load Game",True,(255,165,0))
        creditText = newFont.render("Credits",True,(255,165,0))

    elif slc == 2:
        loadText = newFont.render("Load Game",True,BLUE)
        newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,(255,165,0))
        creditText = newFont.render("Credits",True,(255,165,0))

    elif slc == 3:
        creditText = newFont.render("Credits",True,BLUE)
        loadText = newFont.render("Load Game",True,(255,165,0))
        newText = newFont.render("New Game",True,(255,165,0))

    surface.blit(titleText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - titleText.get_width() / 2, titleText.get_height()))
    surface.blit(titleText2,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - titleText2.get_width() / 2, titleText.get_height() + titleText.get_height()))
    surface.blit(newText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - newText.get_width() / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT * 0.33333))
    surface.blit(loadText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - newText.get_width() / 2, (WINDOWHEIGHT * 0.33333) + loadText.get_height()))
    surface.blit(creditText,(WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - newText.get_width() / 2, (WINDOWHEIGHT * 0.33333) + creditText.get_height() * 2))

    pygame.display.update()

#Draw opening scene
def drawOpening():
    openingFinished = False
    surface.fill((255,255,255))

    #Play theme tune
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Resources/Menu/8-Bit.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(1000)

    #Draw background
    background = Image("Resources/Menu/The 8-Bit Developers.png", 4, 4, 0, 0)
    background = Image("Resources/Menu/The 8-Bit Developers.png", 4, 4, WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - background.image.get_width() / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2 - background.image.get_height() / 2)
    surface.blit(background.image,background.rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(2000)
    openingFinished = True

#Main Loop
def main(newGame):
    running = True
    global slc
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 10)

    #a = pygame.image.load("Resources/Menu/Icon.png")
    #pygame.display.set_icon(a)

    pygame.init()

    if newGame == True:
        #Start game and then music
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) # setup mixer to avoid sound lag
        surface.fill((255,255,255))
        drawOpening()

        #pygame.mixer.music.load("Resources/Menu/Disasterpeace - Home.ogg")
        pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join("Resources","Menu","Disasterpeace - Home.ogg"))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

    while running:
        #Controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and openingFinished == True:

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    slc -= 1
                    if slc == 0:
                        slc = 3

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    slc += 1
                    if slc == 4:
                        slc = 1

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if slc == 1:
                        #new game
                        pass

                    if slc == 2:
                        #resume game
                        pass

                    if slc == 3:
                        #credits
                        pass

        drawMenu()
        pygame.display.flip()

        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join("Resources","Menu","Disasterpeace - Home.ogg"))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

        clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(True)
```

I want to say a big thank you to PyNEwbie for trying to help me, and listening to my problem.